# Python Dataframe that calculate percentage change by lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

How could I calculate the percentage change in python dataframe with using lambda.
The dataframe:
[raw dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75I41.png)

and I would like to calculate the percentage change of volume of each row
The result should be like:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s19Im.png)

I tried that:
df.Volume.map(lambda x: ((df.Volumne.iloc[i+1])-x)/x, i)
but the result is not corrent. 
how could I perform: current value - previous value or next value - current value in lambder expression?
p.s. I know that pct.change() is the method that can easily calculate percentage change.

---

after I tried shift():
[using shift() within lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfLL7.png)

Comment: [df.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) might be a good place to start

Comment: You can use (df['Volume']-df['Volume'].shift())/df['Volume'].shift()

Answer (score 2):

Use the `shift` method of dataframes:

```
>>> df['Volume_pct1'] = (df.Volume - df.Volume.shift(1)) / df.Volume.shift(1)
```

Comment: but how can I make it into a lambda expression?

Comment: @M.THY, Why use a sledgehammer to crack a nut?